# What is the best practice to retrieve Facebook user picture with Firebase in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook

I have the following method in a ViewModel to handle user clicks on a Facebook login button:

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FacebookLogin

/// A view model that handles login and logout operations.
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var isAnon = false
    
    private var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    private let authRef = Auth.auth()
    
    /// A login manager for Facebook.
    private let loginManager = LoginManager()
    
    
    /// Listens to state changes made by Firebase operations.
    func listen()  {
        handle = authRef.addStateDidChangeListener {[self] (auth, user) in
            if user != nil {
                self.isAnon = false
                self.user = User(id: user!.uid, fbId: authRef.currentUser!.providerData[0].uid, name: user!.displayName!, email: user!.email!, profilePicURL: user!.photoURL)
            } else {
                self.isAnon = true
                self.user = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    /// Logs the user in using `loginManager`.
    ///
    /// If successful, get the Facebook credential and sign in using `FirebaseAuth`.
    ///
    /// - SeeAlso: `loginManager`.
    func facebookLogin() {
       
        loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: nil) { [self] loginResult in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success:
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: AccessToken.current!.tokenString)
                authRef.signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Facebook auth with Firebase error: \(error)")
                        return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    
}
```

In `listen()`, I'm trying to build my `User` model whenever Firebase detects state change (i.e., when a user is logged in). My `User` model is a simple `struct` like this:

```swift
/// A model for the current user.
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var fbId: String
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var profilePicURL: URL?
}
```

### The Problem

Right now, as you can see in my `listen()` method, I'm using Firebase's `photoURL` to get user's profile picture. However, it will only give me a low-quality thumbnail pic.

I would love to fetch normal photos from Facebook.

### What I have tried

I tried, in my `facebookLogin()` to call `GraphRequest` to get the picture url. However, since my function is synchronous, I couldn't store the result to my `User` model.

I also tried directly using the Graph API link like "http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=normal", but it seems like it's no longer the safe/suggested practice.

### Question

Given my ViewModel structure, what is the best way to fetch and store Facebook user picture URL to my `User` model?

Comment: Seems like you have at least a couple of options: 1) Use the `GraphRequest` and don't set your `User` model until you get the result back. 2) Set your `User` model as you are now and then *update* it with a new URL once your `GraphRequest` comes back.

Comment: I highly recommend looking into Swift's optional binding syntax so that you can use `if let user = user` rather than `if user != nil` and then using `!` to force unwrap.

Comment: Thank you, I just found out that Firebase's `photoURL` is the default Facebook URL, to get the normal pic URL, I just need to append "?type=normal" to `photoURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Firebase's `photoURL` is Facebook's Graph API URL: `http://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture`. So, to get other sizes, all I need to do is to append a query string like `?type=normal` to the `photoURL`.

To use `GraphRequest`, consider @jnpdx's suggestion:

> Seems like you have at least a couple of options: 1) Use the
> GraphRequest and don't set your User model until you get the result
> back. 2) Set your User model as you are now and then update it with a
> new URL once your GraphRequest comes back.